# How to Join Two Last Non-Empty Lines Before a Specific Pattern?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
1.58%
0009
1991
/////////////////////////
Phil
ttr0018
1991
/////////////////////////
```

Now **I want to join two last non-empty lines before** `/////////////////////////` lines like following (**what output I want**):

```
1.58%
0009 1991
/////////////////////////
Phil
ttr0018 1991
/////////////////////////
```

I tried following regex but not working:

```
Find : ^(\h*\S.*)(?=\R+(?:\h*\S.*\R+)?/{24})
Replace : \1
```

Where is problem?

Comment: What do you want as the output, [edit] the question to show examples.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I told in question!! - check question again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are using a single match with a capture group in your regex, where the replacement with group 1 will give back the same result.

What yo might do is use 2 capture groups, and replace with `$1 $2`

```
^(\h*\S.*)(?:\R\h*)*\R(\h*\S.*)(?:\R\h*)*(?=\R/{24})
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4oGbKU/1)

Or a bit shorter, using `$1 $2\n` in the replacement.

```
^(\h*\S.*)\R\s*^(\h*\S.*)\R\s*^(?=/{24})
```

The pattern matches:

- `(\h*\S.*)` Capture **group 1**, match optional leading horizontal whitespace chars, at least a non whitespace char and the rest of the line
- `\R\s*^` Match a newline, optional whitespace chars and assert the start of the string
- `(\h*\S.*)` Capture **group 2**, same pattern as group 1
- `\R\s*^` Same as previous pattern
- `(?=/{24})` Positive lookahead, assert 24 times a `/` char

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F2Uf8J/1)

[image]

---

As a **side note**, using `^(\h*\S.*)` can by itself also match only forward slashes.

If you want to prevent that, you could use for example a negative lookahead to assert not 24 times a forward slash

```
^(?!/{24})
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, I overlooked non-empty part

Comment: @anubhava I wanted to place a comment under your answer that there might be empty lines in between, but you deleted your answer. (not my dv btw)