# select area of consecutive lines that start with a character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
ABC
44234234
GHG
FGyhyh
Nov2016
/////////////////////////
ABCtt
44234234
GHG
00
FGyhyh
Nov2015
/////////////////////////
ABC
44234234
GHG
hyh
Jan2022
/////////////////////////
```

with `^[A-Za-z].*\R([A-Za-z].*)$` regex I can select consecutive lines that start with a character but now I want to select whole of that area in my list, this mean between two `/////////////////////////` that placed before and after my regex targets.
for example in above list I want to select followings:

```
ABC
44234234
GHG
FGyhyh
Nov2016

ABC
44234234
GHG
hyh
Jan2022
```

I tried following regex but I failed:

```
^/+\R\K(?:(?!/+$|^[A-Za-z].*\R[A-Za-z].*$).*\R)*^[A-Za-z].*(?:\R[A-Za-z].*)*(?:\R(?!/+$).*)*(?=\R/+$)
^/+\R\K(?:(?!/+$|\d[\d,]*\R\d[\d,]*$).*\R)*^[A-Za-z].*(?:\R[A-Za-z].*)*(?:\R(?!/+$).*)*(?=\R/+$)
```

**note that following regex working good for consecutive lines that start with a number:**

```
^/+\R\K(?:(?!/+$|\d[\d,]*\R\d[\d,]*$).*\R)*\d[\d,]*(?:\R\d[\d,]*)+(?:\R(?!/+$).*)*(?=\R/+$)
```

but I don't know how to re-write this regex for character lines!
**note that regex must skip date lines.**

Comment: Try this:
`^/+\R(?:.*\R)*?\K(?:^[A-Za-z].*\R)+(?=(?:.*\R)*?^/+$)`

Comment: @SourabhBurse not working

Comment: Why should it not match block that starts with `ABCtt` line?

Comment: @anubhava because line after `ABCtt` start with a number!

Comment: Not clear because a number line `44234234` is present in all 3 blocks.

Comment: @anubhava `^[A-Za-z].*\R([A-Za-z].*)$` this regex only bookmark some values in block 1 and block 3! (it bookmark some values in block 2 but in end of this post I told regex must skip date lines!)

Comment: @anubhava I need `^[A-Za-z].*\R(?:\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b.*(*SKIP)(*F)|([A-Za-z].*))` area

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Join Two Last Non-Empty Lines Before a Specific Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77912924/how-to-join-two-last-non-empty-lines-before-a-specific-pattern)

Comment: @AndreiOdegov: No that doesn't answer this problem. Please read details of this problem where OP wants to match complete block not just 2 lines.

Comment: With all the comments and replies I still don't understand your question. @anubhava asked, "Why should it not match block that starts with ABCtt line?" You replied, "...because line after ABCtt start with a number!", to which anubhava observed, "...a number line 44234234 is present in all 3 blocks" to which I see no further explanation by you. Also, you said, "regex must skip date lines", yet you selected anubhava's answer that requires the last line to be a date. Which is it? Lastly, please respond to questions asking for clarification by editing your question rather than issuing a  comment.

Comment: I'm also unclear about the question. As I understand there are multiple lines starting with a letter followed by a line containing a number, after this there must not be another line with a number? I tried [`^(\R?\pL.*+)+\R\d.*(?1)*(?:\R\d(*SKIP)(*F))?`](https://regex101.com/r/2RXgcl/1) which works for your sample data but unclear if it follows your desired pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^(?:[A-Za-z\d].*\R)+?(?:[A-Za-z].*\R){2}(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EqLCay/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:[A-Za-z\d].*\R)+?`: Lazily match 1+ lines matching with letter or digits
- `(?:[A-Za-z].*\R){2}`: Match 2 lines starting with a letter
- `(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}$`: Match a line that starts with month string followed by 4 digit year

Comment: I've noticed you have an uncanny ability to achieve a mindmeld with OP's.